# Plotly (Python/Express): Setting min-width on a chart and legend

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to figure out a way to set min-width on a plotly chart because the chart completely collapses into a single line when the window is too small. I want to be able to add a min-width so that it only resizes up to that min-width and then doesn't collapse further.

```
fig1 = go.Figure()
fig1.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[1, 2, 3],
        y=[1, 3, 1]))
fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig1.update_layout(title="Random Chart to show Watermark")
fig1.show()
```

[image: This is what I've been getting]

Comment: Can you include the code you've used to generate the chart you've gotten so far? That would help making your example reproducible

Comment: @DerekO I haven't done anything too big. You can see the code now, just added two traces. Trying to figure out a better way to display my charts because I like the autosizing but only to a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the figure in `.update_layout` and then change the configuration options when you call `.show`:

```
fig1.show(config={"responsive": False})
```

This will prevent the figure from resizing when the browser window is resized, so the figure will remain at the width that you specified.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. And also wouldn't this create a static chart?

Comment: it creates a chart that won't resize at all regardless of the browser window size - if you want it to resize only to a certain point, i am not sure plotly configs support this specific of a feature, but it might be worth checking out the documentation

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for because I do like the resize feature but the chart completely collapsing into a single line doesn't make it very useful. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't reproduce this issue in Chrome as the browser window cannot be resized to below a certain width

Comment: I am using Chrome.